# Proper way to Call a POJO method from EL in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, el

I have the following code:

```
public class ChatUser {
public ChatUser(String UserId, boolean isSelected) {
    this.UserId = UserId;
    this.isSelected = isSelected;     
}
public String getUserId() {
    return UserId;
}
public void setUserId(String UserId) {
    this.UserId = UserId;
}
public boolean isIsSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}
public void setIsSelected(boolean isSelected) {
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}    
private String UserId;
private boolean isSelected;    

}
```

And I'm accessing the method from EL

```
<rows>
    <c:forEach var="user"  items='${requestScope.userList}'        varStatus="indexnum" >   
        <row id="${user.getUserId()}">
            <cell>${user.isIsSelected()}</cell>
            <cell>${user.getUserId()}</cell>
        </row> 
    </c:forEach>
</rows>
```

But it is giving the following error:

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: class s.getUserId()
```

Sometimes it works but not consistent.

[image: JSP Error]

Comment: Sorry i posted the wrong error  - This one is showing : - javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: class s.getUserId()

Answer (score -1):

Camel case must be used in field name of Java Bean. Variable name should be userId and selected. In your case, use following:

```
<rows>
    <c:forEach var="user"  items='${requestScope.userList}' varStatus="indexnum" >   
        <row id="${user.UserId}">
            <cell>${user.isSelected}</cell>
            <cell>${user.UserId}</cell>
        </row> 
    </c:forEach>
</rows>
```

Comment: Edit `<row id="${user.getUserId()}">` too.

Comment: java bean property is accessed with property name only. Since field used is private String UserId; , el must be ${user.UserId} only.

Comment: In the mentioned line it's like `user.getUserId`. Asked you to edit that. Edited on your behalf :)

Comment: misunderstood your statement. Edited my answer now.